Why does my RemoteIP conf cause Apache2 configtest to fail?

Apache 2.4.52
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
AWS EC2 server behind load balancers

I was using %{X-Forwarded-For}i to get the client IP in the logs for fail2ban to process, until I read this in the conf file.

Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
Use mod_remoteip instead.

So I checked and remoteip was already installed and loaded, It is loaded in remoteip.load with the following line:
LoadModule remoteip_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_remoteip.so

I created a remoteip.conf and put the following lines in it.
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPTrustedProxy = 35.170.149.235 52.202.248.219 34.232.106.28 54.234.162.178 3.232.179.245 44.205.134.80
RemoteIPInternalProxy = 172.0.8.172 172.0.7.138 172.0.7.148 172.0.7.22 172.0.6.0/24 172.0.5.0/24 172.0.0.233

When I run apachectl configtest I get this:
scottd:/etc/apache2$ sudo apachectl configtest
AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/remoteip.conf:
RemoteIP: Error parsing IP = (Name or service not known error) for RemoteIPTrustedProxy
Action 'configtest' failed.

If I rotate the RemoteIPInternalProxy line above RemoteIPTrustedProxy it complains about the RemoteIPInternalProxy line.
I removed all the IP's but one and I still get the error?
I just don't see any error in this very simple config file?

Look at this line in the error:
RemoteIP: Error parsing IP = (Name or service not known error) for RemoteIPTrustedProxy

The config is choking on the = sign as indicated here; it’s trying to process the = as an IP address:
Error parsing IP =

Knowing that, try removing the = signs from each line:
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 35.170.149.235 52.202.248.219 34.232.106.28 54.234.162.178 3.232.179.245 44.205.134.80
RemoteIPInternalProxy 172.0.8.172 172.0.7.138 172.0.7.148 172.0.7.22 172.0.6.0/24 172.0.5.0/24 172.0.0.233

